Book about Judas retiring to an isolated place and mistaken for a righteous one
A friend once told me about a fiction book they had read, where Judas (of the New Testament) supposedly didn't die, but escaped to an island (or an otherwise isolated place) to hide from his shame. Decades later the locals get a wind that Christianity is becoming a popular religion and that the man living among them is likely a former disciple of Jesus. They decide to make a bit of business out of it, by inviting pilgrims and selling souvenirs with Judas depictions, etc. The climax occurs when Judas discovers the stocks of the goods prepared for sale.
(Needless to say that the account and the time frame are highly improbable, most likely meant to illustrate some modern ideas and absurdities.)
I will appreciate a more precise reference to this story (title, author, etc.).

For the [[tag:title]] tag, please read the description: "Do not use to ask for the title of a work you partially remember; use [identification-request] instead"

List of some fiction and non-fiction books about Judas.
